# How to set puppet on the agent to start on reboots?

Tags: ubuntu, puppet

I'm on ubuntu, is this the correct way to get puppet to start on reboots?

update-rc.d puppet default

If yes, where can I see the result of that command?  Does it update a file that gets called on reboots?

Is this the same process for both the puppet master server and the puppet agent servers?

**Update**
Just in case the puppet agent already runs after reboots using the default installs on ubuntu using:

```
sudo apt-get puppet facter
```

How can I know if is already setup to start on reboots?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The puppet agent package doesn't set itself to start at boot by default, so that you have a chance to configure it as needed before it starts doing its thing (and potentially making massive changes to the system).  It warns about this when you try to start the service.

Modify `/etc/default/puppet`, changing `START=no` to `START=yes`, then start the service with `service puppet start`.

The puppetmaster package should be starting at boot automatically as soon as it's installed.

Comment: how should I be starting/stoping the puppetmaster, using service puppet restart, or /etc/init.d/puppetmaster or invoke-rc.d ?  which one is the best way here?

Comment: `service puppetmaster restart` or `/etc/init.d/puppetmaster restart`; the "proper" way is with the `service` command.  Note that the "puppet" service is the agent only, while "puppetmaster" is for the master.

Comment: `puppet module install cprice404/inifile; puppet apply -e "ini_setting { enablepuppet: ensure => present, path => '/etc/default/puppet', section => '', setting => 'START', value => 'yes' }"`

Answer (score 3):

The puppet way, once you have puppet installed you can use puppet resource (or ralsh on 0.25):

```
puppet resource service puppet ensure=running enable=true
```

Answer (score 1):

That should set the service to start on boot. You can do a ls of /etc/rcX.d/*puppet (where X is the default runlevel of your system) to make sure it is set to come up on boot. If there is a puppet file with a capital S, it is set (for example, S85puppet). The "S" at the beginning tells the system to execute the script at startup.

Comment: what would my default run level be? I'm not sure.  it's a new ec2 instance.

Comment: ok I found S21puppet in many of the rc4.d etc folders.

Comment: when I do a: px aux I don't see puppet anywhere in the list, that is confusing me.

Comment: actually looking at the run folder, it sais PID 573, so using ps aux I see:  /usr/bin/ruby1.   that's a pretty cryptic way of knowing that it is puppet agent running no?

Comment: To determine your default renlevel, run the following: grep id /etc/inittab. The result will have a number between two colons, that is the default runlevel. You can also run "who -r" to show the current runlevel (in case it was changed since bootup).

Comment: I don't have a /etc/inittab file, but who -r shows 2.

Comment: @Blankman Use `runlevel` to know in which run level you are. I think Debian starts on run level 3 by default, and I'm not sure how, or if, Ubuntu varies from that.

Comment: @Blankman Just checked this [faq](http://www.debian.org/doc/FAQ/ch-customizing.en.html), Debian is run level 2 by default.

Answer (score 0):

I like to put a puppet agent run in /etc/rc.local so that puppet will apply a fresh catalog upon boot, and will log any changes to the console.

do:

```
echo "puppetd --test" >> /etc/rc.local
```